# 32bit float implementation with Faster RCNN

Tags: floating-point, 32-bit, faster-rcnn

I am having issues with training a faster RCNN with 32bit floating point images. Most implementations work well with 8bit images.
Can anyone provide any information on this or how I can go about this??

Each time I tried to do the training, it would throw an error specifying that I can’t use 32bit float. Reducing the precision of my images leads to loss of features and poor performance.

Please, what can I likely do?